# Get Absolute URL in Django when using Class Based Views

Tags: python, django

Hello I am migrating my app to use class based views instead of function based views. In my old code I was able to get the absolute URL of an object related to a function view this way:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self',null=True,blank=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog.views.showcategory',args=[str(self.slug)])
```

I couldn't find what I should change in my get absolute url function in order to get the same result.

This is my new class based view

```
class CategoryView(ListPosts):
    template_name = "postlist.html"
    context_object_name="posts"
    def get_queryset(self):
         return Post.objects.filter(category__slug=self.kwargs['slug']).order_by('created')
```

Thanks!

Comment: What does the appropriate line in your urlconf look like? And what error does Django throw at you?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should always give your URLs a name, and refer to that:

```
url(r'/category/(?P<slug>\w+)/$', CategoryView.as_view(), name='category_view'),
```

Now:

```
@models.permalink
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return ('category_view', (), {'slug': self.slug})
```

Note I've used the permalink decorator, which does the same as calling `reverse` but is a bit neater.

Comment: According to the 1.6 docs, the permalink decorator is no longer recommended: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/instances/#the-permalink-decorator

Comment: According to the django docs you need to use `reverse()` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url

Answer (score 12):

Here is my `get_absolute_url` configuration:

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^products/(?P<slug>[\w\d\-\_]+)/$', views.ProductView.as_view(), name='product'),
    )
```

**models.py**

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('products:product', kwargs={'slug':self.slug})
```

My urls.py is under the "products" app, so the url namespace is "products:product"

Comment: And if the regexp were not named like so : url(r'^products/([\w\d\-\_]+)/$', views.ProductView.as_view(), name='product'),
    ) how you would inject the parameter kwargs ? kwargs = self.slug does not work.

Comment: @Reveclair `kwargs` is a key word argument dictionary, so you wouldn't want to set it equal to `self.slug`.  You can inject parameters into `kwargs` like any other python dictionary. i.e. `kwargs['foo'] = 'bar'`. In addition, for Django, only named URL parameters get injected into `kwargs`, so it is important to name them in the URL regex.

Answer (score 3):

The 2018 answer to this question is basically the same as @Aaron's, but for quick access here it is:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    from django.urls import reverse
    return reverse('people.views.details', args=[str(self.id)])
```

From https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url

Answer (score 0):

This function worked for me, it uses multiple parameters:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
return reverse('video', kwargs={'slug':self.chapiter.course.slug,'chpiter_slug':self.chapiter.chpiterSlug,'pk':str(self.index).zfill(2)})
```

Comment: Could you explain why/how that works? Also, are 'chapiter' and 'chpiter' supposed to be 'chapter'?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you do it in `Django >= 2.0`.

In `urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path

app_name = 'my_app'

urlpatterns = [
    path('products/<slug:slug>', views.ProductDetailView.as_view(), name='products')
]
```

Add the following code to your `models.py`

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=125)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    # rest of the fields

   def get_absolute_url(self):
         return reverse('my_app:products', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

For displaying the detail, add a generic view in your `views.py`

```
class ProductDetailView(DetailView):
     template_name = 'my_app/detail.html'

     def get_queryset(self):
         return Product.objects.all()
```